# Does rosbag play with multiple bags and -s and -u parameters know not to fully load bags that don't overlap with those times?

Tags: ros, rosbag

If rosbag play were to quickly get start and end times for each bag provided for playback it could discard those that don't overlap at all, once it knows what the full time span of all the bags are (because -s is relative to the earliest time in any of the bags, and -u is relative to that)- or does it already do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is an optimization that has been made. I'm not sure what "discarding" the bag would do exactly. If the bags are indexed it's likely to not cause a lot of overlap if the contents are outside the playback parameters. To justify adding this extra complexity it would be helpful to see some measurements that are showing that this aspect is a bottleneck for some use case(s) that would be reduced or removed.

Comment: I have an external drive that's slow relative to internal drives, a single 1GB rosbag load could take ten or more seconds the first time it's done (after which it's cached for a while and can be loaded in a fraction of a second)- I believe they are indexed, rosbag info doesn't indicate that they aren't.  If there were a method to get start and end times without incurring that full load cost rosbag play (or a wrapper around it) could be made to scan quickly through the list of provided bags (say 10 or 20) and filter out those outside the time parameters.

Comment: That sounds like a good place to make optimizations for your use case.